# Curved border CSS implementation

Tags: css, border

Recently I saw a design concept on Dribbble, and it's really inspiring me. Especially the sidebar with a curved U-shape at the top and bottom gave me great thoughts on making a tabs stack or flow diagram. I can make it with alpha images, but it would be better to use pure CSS and I don't mind CSS3. However I'm not familiar with CSS3, and hope someone could suggest me a way to do it.

[image: you can see a U-shape concavity at the top and a same shape convexity at the buttom]

*Cropped from http://dribbble.com/shots/1213195-CMS-Concept/attachments/162177*

*Original design at http://dribbble.com/shots/1213195-CMS-Concept*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using CSS3 `transform` property to skew two pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` which are placed at the top of each coloured section. I had to place one as a stub underneath the green to get the green lip showing.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MS5J7/3/)

The main shapes CSS is below:

```
/* Shape */

.flap {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.flap:before, .flap:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2em;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: inherit;
    border-width: 4px;
}
.flap:before {
    left: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: skew(60deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(60deg);
    -o-transform: skew(60deg);
}
.flap:after {
    right: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-60deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-60deg);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is really close. Think I can follow and make some improvements.

Comment: @Rix. I have a less stable version using extra circles, http://jsfiddle.net/yReG5/, which may not play well with your bg texture. Thought I would share it.

Comment: You give me a good suggestion. I'll try on that, and see how far it could be.

Answer (score 3):

There are many good approaches - I wanted to add a solution with a different approach and which is compatible in all HTML5 browsers.

It's not straight-forward and elegant as a pure CSS solution but it uses a canvas to generate the border and therefor also offer extended possibilities to generate the gradients etc.

**[HERE IS AN ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/3GeVs/)**

which results in this:

[image: Example]

Here is a simple example how this can be used from JavaScript:

The function takes three arguments:

1. element to add border to
2. height of the curve
3. color of background

For example:

```
curlyBorder(border1, 24, '#073');
curlyBorder(border2, 24, '#037');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="border1">Text 1</div>
<div id="border2">Text 2</div>
```

**CSS:** (mostly just to define dimension and colors)

```
#border2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
}
#border1, #border2 {
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    padding:30px 16px;
    color:#fff;
    font:26px sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

The function which generates the canvas with graphics and sets it as a background for the element. The code is non-optimized. In any case it can be extended to support gradient, nicer border lines etc. I kept it to a minimum here for the sake of example:

```
function curlyBorder(el, ch, color) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    render();

    function render() {

        var w = el.clientWidth,
            h = el.clientHeight,
            t = w * 0.333;

        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;

        /// define border
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(t, 0);

        /// create one curve positive direction
        renderCurve(t, ch, 1);

        ctx.lineTo(w, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(w, h - ch);
        ctx.lineTo(w - t, h - ch);

        /// create one curve negative direction
        renderCurve(t, ch, -1);

        ctx.lineTo(0, h - ch);
        ctx.closePath();

        /// color or gradient
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();

        /// set this canvas as background to element
        el.style.background = 'url(' + 
            canvas.toDataURL() + ') no-repeat top left';

        /// we use trigonometry to make the curved line:
        function renderCurve(t, ch, d) {

            var x, sx, ex,dg = -90, dgd = 360 / t, y;

            if (d > 0) {
                x = t;
                for(; x < t * 2; x++) {
                    y = ch * 0.5 * Math.sin(dg * Math.PI / 180);
                    ctx.lineTo(x, y + ch * 0.5);
                    dg += dgd;
                }
            } else {
                x = t * 2;
                for(; x > t; x--) {
                    y = ch * 0.5 * Math.sin(dg * Math.PI / 180);
                    ctx.lineTo(x, h - ch * 0.5 + y);
                    dg += dgd;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The drawbacks with this is that is not as efficient as CSS however, performance is more than acceptable if kept to a few elements only.

You need to adjust positions of the elements. I hard coded the next element with position relative and an offset - this can be solved much better other ways through other CSS rules (or even implemented in the function itself).

On the positive side though: you have more liberty in the design possibilities and you can change sizes and get a high quality render compared to using an image that is scaled.

It will render the same in all HTML5 browsers that support canvas (I think even IE < 9 with exCanvas will be able to render this but I haven't checked).

Comment: Nice try and great look! Although we don't often use canvas for regular web pages, it can be included in some kind of canvas applications.

Comment: Wow! This is great! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create normal border at the end of each div and then place shapes in absolute positioning at the centre of the div,

You can draw shapes using CSS 3 using border property..

```
.semicirclebottom{
 height:45px;
 width:90px;
 border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 background:green;
 }

 .oval{
 height:180px;
 width:45px;
 border-radius: 90px / 45px;
 -moz-border-radius:90px / 45px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 90px / 45px;
 background:green;
 }
```

Using curved triangle can bring it close to your requirement..

```
 div {
transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
background-color:green;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:-50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but there's no way to achieve that effect. You could use an :after pseudo-element to make a square with rounded corners, rotate it and position it, but that's the closest you could get, and it still wouldn't look particularly good.

I think using graphics (images/SVG) would be the best solution.

EDIT: Had a crack at some CSS using Prasanna's idea, this is what I came up with. Not the best, but it's the closest I can get.

```
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.semicirclebottom{
    height:40px;
    width:80px;
    border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    bottom: -20px;
    z-index: 999999;
 }

.green {
    background: green;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gbLB/2/

Answer (score 0):

I copied Prasanna's ans.. This the closest I got..

http://jsfiddle.net/P2PEH/

```
.semicirclebottom{
 margin-right: 100px;
 height:50px;
 width:120px;
 border-radius: 0 0 120px 120px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 120px 120px;
 -webkit-border-radius:  0 0 140px 140px;
 background:green;
margin-left:170px;
 }

.rectangle {    
 height:180px;
width:545px;
 background:green;
}
```

Err.. Terrible way of coding, I guess.. SVG can do the magic. But the first image with black background tiled pattern, I doubt SVG too

Answer (score 0):

Check the Js fiddle

Modification of cjross fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MS5J7/6/

```
.blue-flap {
    background-color: #4DA0E3;
    border-top: 4px solid #4DA0E3;
}

.green-flap {
    background-color: #65DA83;
    border-top: 4px solid  #65DA83;
}
.brown-flap {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-top: 4px solid #222222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt, playing with borders, transforms and other stuff in the `:after`and `:before` pseudo elements.

[image]

Of course, then you can adjust the values to get a pixel-perfect result.
But I can't recreate the little border, or shadow, under the shape... :/

<kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/WHvsM/**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, this is a good way. Maybe I can use JavaScript to dynamically add the empty div thus it won't distort the semanteme.