# Can I have some ups and downs to div borders using css?

Tags: css, border

[image: The image shows a div with random border?]
Can we have border something like this using css ?

Comment: I think it better to use svg or image.. but you can style it with css and use pseudo element(not only by one border:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502801/curved-border-css-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Borders are limited for a `div`. Multiple box-shadows can do some work but it will be a lot of work. Why don't you use SVG? I suggest you to use SVG, its light and most of the websites today use it. And you can animate SVGs!

Comment: As you can do this with a `div`, lots of work though, I removed the "No" in your answer + upvoted.

Comment: Avoid answer badly formatted questions like this. They should also contain an attempt, as just posting a picture and ask others to do the work is not what SO is for.